# Why won't Google let me login to YouTube?

Tags: google, youtube, account-management, google-account

It's been a while since I logged into YouTube. I just reset my password, and tried to login with my old username and the password I just set.  I received a message saying I had to login with my Google account and it inserted my email address (that is connected to the YouTube account) into the email box.  Here's the thing:

That email address it inserted?  **It's not a Google account.**  It's not a Google email address.

I've tried every *possible* password I can think of, including (but not limited to) the password I just set it to, the Google account's password, and that email address's password.

When I *do* try to login with my Google email address, it wants to make me a new channel.

How can I regain control over my YouTube account?

Comment: Well, I regained control of my account, but in the process I accidentally created a second Google account...

Comment: I was able to [move it from one account to the other](http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?answer=58582), though.